# Ballerina pdf library

Tags: pdf, server-side, ballerina

I am a newbie in using Ballerina and like to generate pdf files on server side for providing it to the client. Is there a library or a smart way to do that in Ballerina?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Ballerina does not have a such module so far. It would be great if one could implement one and contribute to [Ballerina Central](https://central.ballerina.io/).

You can use Ballerina interop to integrate with existing Java library. You can read more about Ballerina interop in this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/ballerina-interop-and-all-you-need-to-know)